# Generate schematic (geographic) diagram from graph

Tags: python, maps, graph-theory, graphviz, diagram

I would like to know how best to generate a schematic diagram, something like [this](https://pdfhost.io/v/Q2czMawSD_201011_TAG4), from a graph (created using the Python NetworkX library) that contains the latitude and longitude of each node (city) and the lines connecting them in the Indian railway network.

- The cities (nodes) should be located reasonably close to their actual position, but not necessarily exactly. I am OK with using the *plate carrée* projection that simply maps lat/long onto X/Y in the diagram.
- The rail lines (edges) can be straight lines or even curves if it fits better.
- On the diagram should be displayed the cities (preferably as dots) along with a short (max 4 characters) label for each, the lines connecting them, and a single label for each line (the given example has quite long labels for the lines).
- Preferably the amount of manual tweaking of coordinates to get things to fit should be minimised.

Using Graphviz was my first idea. But I don't know how well neato/fdp (required for fixed positioning of nodes) will perform with large numbers of nodes/edges. Also, making Graphviz display labels separately outside the nodes (rather than inline) seems to need a lot of manual positioning of each label, which would be pretty boring. Is there any better way to get this kind of layout?

Answer (score 1):

Doable (https://forum.graphviz.org/t/another-stupid-graphviz-trick-geographic-graphs/256), but does not seem to use many Graphviz features.  In addition to tools mentioned in the link, maybe consider **pikchr** (https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/homepage.md)